# pass to another jsf page

Tags: jsf

i am trying to pass a parameter from a jsf page to another but the problem that the another page i am calling to doesn't change even the URl and it just add "#" to the existing url . 
this is index.xhtml

```
        <h:commandLink value="details" action="#{ideeBean.details()}">
                  <f:param name="idee" value="in" />
              </h:commandLink>
```

this is IdeeBean.java

```
 public String details(){

      return "details";
  }
```

and when i click the commandlink the url pass from :http://localhost:8080/gidee/ to http://localhost:8080/gidee/# .

Comment: You need `h:outputLink` to use `f:param` parameters, or `h:commandLink action="#{ideeBean.details(yourParameterValue1, yourParameterValue2)}"` to pass parameters to your action method.

Comment: i want to pass to the url http://localhost:8080/gidee/details.xhtml so the method details() in index.xhtml is correct ? because it pass to http://localhost:8080/gidee/# .

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the url you need to do a redirect after the action completes.

Comment: redirect you mean i should use return "details?faces-redirect=true" in the details method ? i try this too but nothing changes

Comment: Yes, either the mapping of outcome "details"should be "details.xhtml" in faces-config or the action method should return details.xhtml?faces-redirect=true.